# Custom listview not refresh after insert data from dialog to SQLi

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I insert data to SQLi from dialog like this

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put(DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, 1);
                        cv.put(DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME, "driver");
                        cv.put(DBHelper.COL_DATE, mDisplayDate.getText().toString());

                        db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
                        cursor.requery();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });
```

I query data in function onResume() to show in list view like this.

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    lst_driver.clear();

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] queryColumns = new String[]{"_id", DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME,DBHelper.COL_DATE };
    cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns, null,null,
           null,null,null);

    HashMap<String,String> map ;
    String vh_name;

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,String>();

        vh_name= dbHelper.VehicleType(cursor.getString(1));
        map.put("vehicle_type", vh_name);
        map.put("date", cursor.getString(3));
        lst_driver.add(map);


    }

    String[] showColumns = new String[]{"vehicle_type", "date"};
    int[] views = new int[] {R.id.ColType, R.id.ColDate};

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DriverLicenseActivity.this,lst_driver, R.layout.activity_list_layout, showColumns, views);
    lv_driver.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

After I insert data it not show in list view. I have to open this activity again then it will appear in list view. How to show data in list view after insert to SQLi ?

Comment: Have u used the `notifyDataChanged()` after adding the items in **ArrayList**

Comment: Add your **Adapter** class also

Comment: first check on resume method called or not? and also post adpter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your getting of data in one functionality and simply call it after you insert data from `onClick` and on `onResume()`

```
private void getData() {

  lst_driver.clear();

  db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  String[] queryColumns = new String[]{"_id", DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME,DBHelper.COL_DATE };
  cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns, null,null,
       null,null,null);

  HashMap<String,String> map ;
  String vh_name;

  while(cursor.moveToNext())
  {
    map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    vh_name= dbHelper.VehicleType(cursor.getString(1));
    map.put("vehicle_type", vh_name);
    map.put("date", cursor.getString(3));
    lst_driver.add(map);


  }

  String[] showColumns = new String[]{"vehicle_type", "date"};
  int[] views = new int[] {R.id.ColType, R.id.ColDate};

  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DriverLicenseActivity.this,lst_driver, R.layout.activity_list_layout, showColumns, views);
  lv_driver.setAdapter(adapter);

  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call it on your `onResume` and after you insert data from `onClickListener`:

```
public void onResume() {
  getData();
}

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put(DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, 1);
                    cv.put(DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME, "driver");
                    cv.put(DBHelper.COL_DATE, mDisplayDate.getText().toString());

                    db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
                    cursor.requery();
                    getData();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your onResume method is called before the SQLite insert. I would recommand you to separate the part where you update the adapter and call this method instantly after the insert.